# HELM: include named template inside tpl .Files.Get fails

Tags: kubernetes-helm

**structure of folders:**

```
files
  alertmanager
    rules
      - alertmanager.rules
      - nodes.rules
      ...
templates
  - _helpers.tpl
  - prometheus.yaml
```

**files/alertmanager/rules/alertmanager.rules**

```yaml
- name: Alertmanager
  rules:
    - alert: PrometheusAlertmanagerConfigurationReloadFailure
      expr: |
        # Without max_over_time, failed scrapes could create false negatives, see
        # https://www.robustperception.io/alerting-on-gauges-in-prometheus-2-0 for details.
        max_over_time(alertmanager_config_last_reload_successful{app_kubernetes_io_name="alertmanager"}[5m]) == 0
      for: 10m
      labels:
        severity: critical
        {{ include _default_rule_labels . }}
      annotations:
        type: Alertmanager
        summary: Prometheus AlertManager configuration reload failure
        description: |
          The error could be caused by recent changes and could be caused by an incorrect configuration of alertmanager template (defined in templates/prometheus.yaml).
          Or it can be caused by incorrect route(s) configuration (typically in argocd/apps/values.yaml)
```

**templates/_helpers.tpl**

```yaml
{{/*
Collect alertmanager rules from files
*/}}
{{- define "alertmanager.rules" -}}
{{- range $path, $_ := .Files.Glob "files/alertmanager/rules/**.rules" }}
{{ tpl ($.Files.Get $path) $ }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}


{{/*
Set default alert rule labels
*/}}
{{- define "_default_rule_labels" -}}
environment: {{ .Values.environment }}
client: {{ .Values.client }}
cluster: {{ .Values.eks_cluster }}
sla: {{ .Values.sla }}
{{- end }}
```

**templates/prometheus.yaml**

```
# ? PROMETHEUS ALERT RULES
serverFiles:
  alerting_rules.yml:
    groups:
      {{- include "alertmanager.rules" . | nindent 14 }}
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to render the prometheus.yaml template:

```bash
✗  helm template . -s templates/prometheus.yaml
parse error at (root/templates/prometheus.yaml:15): function "_default_rule_labels" not defined
```

### How to approach?

I can render `{{ .Values.something }}` inside **files/alertmanager/rules/alertmanager.rules**, but inclusion of named templates throws an error.

Comment: You need to quote the template name; `include "_default_rule_labels" .`.  The template name for `include` can actually be an arbitrary expression, for some advanced use cases.

Comment: indeed @DavidMaze - can you pls post a formal reply and I will accept it?